Product configurator
I'm helping a few customers with the PowerPlatform using PowerAutomate, BI and Apps for enhanced operations. However I get the question more often to build a product configurator on their website in order to configure products with a PowerApps solution.
However, in order to use PowerApps, you always need a Microsoft licence, is there any way you can work around here and publish an Application on a website where it's optional to login?
Or isn't PowerApps a good solution for this application?
Thanks
